# NameError at / uninitialized constant Main

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using gem 'devise' for authentication in my project. Everything was fine but after adding gem 'cancancan' in my gemfile. Then I logged in as a user  for test my app and saw this "NameError at / uninitialized constant Main".

project gemfile:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'better_errors
```

project models:

ability.rb file:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
  end
end
```

user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

project controller:
main_controller.rb file

```
class MainController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
  end

  def me
  end
end
```

where am I doing wrong? Please give me your advice.

Thanks,
Mezbah

Comment: how did you generate the main `controller` ?

Comment: Manually, rails g controller main.

Comment: I think the problem with 'cancancan'

Comment: controller should be pluralized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load_and_authorize_resource method is provided to automatically authorize all actions in a RESTful style resource controller`

you just don't have `Main` model

Comment: I just say that if you have `Article` model, you could write `load_and_authorize` inside `ArticlesController`, I don't know need you Main resource or no, maybe you just should check authorization rule in other way.